# How to show graphs of functions are perpendicular

Tags: real-analysis, functions, analytic-geometry

I'm stuck on problem 8 from chapter 4 in Spivaks Calculus.

> Prove the graphs of the functions
>
> $f(x)=mx+b$
>
> $g(x)=nx+c$
>
> are perpendicular if $mn=-1$ by computing the squares of the lengths of the sides of the triangle.
>
> [image]

What I tried:

- In right $\Delta ACQ$ we find: $AC^2 = CQ^2 + AQ^2 = 1 + m^2$
- In right $\Delta BCQ$ we find: $BC^2 = CQ^2 + BQ^2 = 1 + n^2$

If we can show that $\angle C$ is a right angle, then we are done.

So assuming $\Delta ABC$ is a right triangle, we would find:

$$AC^2 + BC^2 = AB^2$$

Since $AB=m+n$:

$$AC^2 + BC^2 = (m + n)^2$$

If we plug in the values from above:

$$(1 + m^2) + (1+n^2) = (m + n)^2$$

But that doesn't seem like it's correct or leading anywhere.

Did I miss something? I'm also not sure how to make use of the fact that $mn=-1$, meaning that $m$ is the negative reciprocal of $n$ or vice versa.

Comment: $mn = -1$ is what you want to prove: you cannot make use of it. What happens if you expand the square on the RHS of your last equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Consider that the distance from $(1,m)$ to $(1,n)$ is $(m-n)^2$ ($n$ is a negative number), your final line will now read

$m^2 + n^2 + 2 = (m-n)^2$.

Expand this out and simplify.

Comment: Oh that is correct, thank you. Somehow I didn't see that. But how does the $mn=-1$ come into play in the end? Like, how is it proven?

Comment: So when you simplify the equation you get $mn = -1$. But throughout the whole working your statements have been true if and only if the $AC$ and $BC$ are perpendicular. This means that if $mn = - 1 $ the triangle is a right angled triangle, and therefore the two lines are perpendicular